# Error in ReadRepairStage Cassandra in system.log

Tags: cassandra, nosql, database-replication

Currently we are seeing:

```
ERROR [ReadRepairStage:896014] CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[ReadRepairStage:896014,5,main]
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses in Cassandra system.log.
```

We have kept `read_request_timeout_in_ms` value to 3 seconds, does this impact the background data synching which will be used for maintaining the replication factor.

I have tried increasing the `read_request_timeout_in_ms` value of 1 node in cluster and there hasn’t been much improvement.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this type of issue:

1. Network issues
2. Dropped mutations
   a. Overloaded nodes
   b. IO (CPU, memory, disk) perf issues
3. Long gc pauses

You'll have to diagnose why the read repair is happening. Typically, it's dropped mutations for whatever reason. Or read repair chance. If it's read repair chance, be sure to set `dc_local_read_repair_chance` and `read_repair_chance` to 0. Neither one is needed and it will be set to 0 by default in later builds.